# Trying to do a javascript POST to login

Tags: javascript

I am completely new to javascript and httprequest stuff. I am trying to POST to an api to login and receive back some json user data. I have got this so far and it hits the server and the server shows a 200 but I'm not getting a response.

```
 function LogIn() {


var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
alert(email);
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
alert(password);
var postdata = "email=" + email + "&password=" + password;

  xhr.open("POST", "https://dev.pillwise.eginity.com/api/login/0.json", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.withCredentials = true;
  xhr.send(postdata);

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      alert(xhr.readyState);
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        alert(this.responseText);
    }
    alert(xhr.readyState);
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(xhr.responseText)
  };
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 200 isn't response? May be you are not getting any data.

Comment: What do you get? A timeout? What does the Network tab in you browser's developer tools show? Are there any errors on the console?

Comment: I know there is data there for the user Im logging in. I never get a 200 status though.so it never goes in the if statement.

Comment: I just get nothing, status 0 and no responseText.

Comment: What about the Network tab? What about the Console? A status of 0 usually indicates a network error or security error.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting your Request header to application/json:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

I would also check if the request and reponse are within the same domain. If not, then I would use JSONP or better jQuery `.ajax()`

Comment: "Try setting your Request header to application/json" — Why? The content being sent isn't JSON.

Comment: JSONP is a dirty hack. We've had CORS for years now.

Comment: jQuery's `.ajax()` is a useful convienience function, but won't do anything that the code in the question isn't doing already.

Comment: @Quentin do you have an actual solution to the problem or you just keep making objections? If you know that much then I would suggest you to provide an answer to the problem

Comment: If you bothered to pay attention to the comments on the question you would have noticed that I asked the OP to provide additional information. Identifying the problem with a decent degree of confidence requires that information be provided.

Comment: I think I am having a cross domain issue. when I push it to the server it gets a little further along. running it locally I never a response back.